# Flutter page comes too slow, when page size is high

Tags: flutter

My page contains a flatbutton. When I press on that button, Navigate to another page(It contains 50 textformfield) too slow. How to resolve it?.Here is my code for sample[image: Screenshot shows, the first page is stuck when navigation button pressed. After 5 seconds the next page comes].

```
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}
class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(children: [Table(children: [
        TableRow(children: [Column(children: [Text('Name')],),Column(children: [TextFormField(decoration:InputDecoration())],)]),
        TableRow(children: [Column(children: [Text('Name')],),Column(children: [TextFormField(decoration:InputDecoration())],)]),
        TableRow(children: [Column(children: [Text('Name')],),Column(children: [TextFormField(decoration:InputDecoration())],)]),//repeat 60 times
      ],)],),),);}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use a `Listview.builder` what you're doing currently is painting all 50 textfields at the same time even if they're not on the screen.